# Vscode is not showing tab Output and Problems (Only when when debugging Flutter)

Tags: flutter, vscode-debugger

This is a normal **Panel**: (With all Tab Sections: Problems, Output, Debug Console, Terminal)

[image]

But my VSCODE when debug **Flutter** project shows only two tab options (Terminal - Debug Console) and if I click in terminal the Debug Console tab being hidden... (it only happens with Flutter)

[image]

To restore Hidden Tab I have to close VSCODE and reopen...

Please help me ;)

Comment: See this and follow steps correctly you might missed something out https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/vscode

Comment: Thanks Kevin, the problem is with devtools for Dart!

Comment: Happy that is worked. Good Luck.